# Data type error

Tags: python, types, numpy, python-imaging-library

When I run this code I get the output:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I have no idea why this is happening because I set both of the data types to uint8 and uint64 respectively. Evidently I don't understand data types very well.

```
from PIL import Image

from numpy import random

N = 100

##open an image
im=Image.open('/Users/grahamwarner/Desktop/Experiment/gwarner/labeled_photos/masks/003030.png')

##create a random image
rand_matrix = random.randint(0, 255, (500, 500, 3)).astype('uint8')

rand_image = Image.fromarray(rand_matrix)

##select N random pixels
rand_pix = random.randint(0,499, (N,2)).astype('uint64')

##replace the random values at these pixels with the original values
for ii in range(N):

  rand_image.putpixel(tuple(rand_pix[ii,:]), im.getpixel(tuple(rand_pix[ii,:])))
```

Comment: Which one line did this occur?

Comment: If this question has been answered to your satisfaction, you should accept the best answer, see [faq#howtoask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getpixel` method in PIL seems to be very picky about its input, and specifically wants a tuple of `int`s (which are not the same as Numpy's `uint64` type). The following works for me:

```
for ii in range(N):
    coordinate = tuple(map(int, rand_pix[ii,:]))
    rand_image.putpixel(coordinate, im.getpixel(coordinate))
```